# VBA to click a dynamic href

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to click a link on a website with the tag:

```
<a href="/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:D01441:>D01441</a>
```

However, I'm doing this after searching for a unique item (I have an array of >9000 unique items), and the "D01441" part is different for each item, and I don't know in advance what it will be for each. The following code is in a loop that goes through each item and searches for it one at a time. After searching, I would like to click on a link that appears (the code above) and do more things on that next web page.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim ele As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

...

For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If ele.Href = "/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:D01441" Then
        ele.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The above code doesn't work and I'm not sure why. But once I get it to work, I don't know how to modify the "D01441" part so that I can click on any searched item's link. Here's more html around the link I want:

```
<tbody>
  <tr> ... </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "data1">
      <a href = "/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:D01441:>D01441</a>
    </td>
    <td class = "data1">..</td>
    <td class = "data1">..</td>

...
```

---

EDIT: To try to deal with the changing "D01441", I tried using InStr but it doesn't work either:

```
    For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(ele.Href, "/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:") = 1 Then
            MsgBox "There"
            ele.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I believe you want the `.innerText` property of `ele` (not `.Href`),  which should be equal to `D01441` in your example.

Comment: @dwirony I'm not sure how to incorporate .innerText, because don't I still need to find the right tag by looking at .href?

Comment: If i use .innerText then wouldn't I need to hardcode "D01441"? I need it to be whatever is the correct link on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS selectors:**

Try using a CSS selector combination applied via `querySelector` method of `document` to target the common start part of the `href`.

---

**Applying the selector combination:**

```
IE.document.querySelector("a[href^='/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:']").Click
```

---

**Understanding the selector combination:**

This uses a CSS selector combination to target the element with:

```
a[href^='/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:']
```

This says element with `a` tag having attribute `href` whose value starts with
`'/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:'` . The `^` means starts with.

---

**Query in action:**

Here is the selector in action on your HTML sample:

[image: sample]

---

**Side note:**

If you have multiple elements with `a` tags and an `href` that starts with `/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:`, it will match the first one, in most instances. If that is the case seeing more HTML would help. I think there are a few problems with that HTML sample because in theory a more selective CSS query might be `.data1 a[href^='/dbget-bin/www_bget?dr:']`, so as to include the parent element class of `data1`, `"."` being a class selector.

Comment: Oh i'd never seen that before - thank you it works!! I realized some search queries don't have any results, in that case, is there a way to say If IE.document.querySelector("...") not on page?

Comment: Nvm you can just check if it = 0

Comment: Another awesome approach.

Answer (score 2):

*@QHarr answer is the elegant and best solution, but...*

To address your issue of getting the part number from the href, you can use the `InStr` like this

```
For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Dim partNumber As String
    Dim colonPosition As Long
    colonPosition = InStr(1, ele.Href, ":", vbTextCompare)
    If colonPosition > 0 Then
        partNumber = Right$(ele.Href, Len(ele.Href) - colonPosition)
        Debug.Print partNumber
    End If
Next ele
```